# capture and validate audio as part of test automation

Tags: audio

I am playing a known audio file (all supported standard format), from device1 to another device2 over BT.

"Audio out"  of device 2 is connected to my system AuxIn (Standard Stero jack),

Can some one explain how do i validate that audio received from device 2 which should be automated?

-Thanks in advance,
Manju

Comment: There are many things that can be measured. There are numerous traditional measurements such as frequency response, THD+N, etc. Or if your trying to determine speech quality there are technologies like PESQ or POLQA. If you can provide more details, I may be able to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

This question isn't new and I don't have the perfect answer to this but since it's the first result when searching for 'audio automation' I will share what I have learned so far in my efforts to run automated audio tests on an app that uses VOIP:

- I'm using [Sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) which is a very powerful tool for audio analysis.  It supports silence removal, [VAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_activity_detection), noise reduction etc.
- For simulating mic input I found it useful to use a virtual audio cable driver which directs your audio output to your audio input.  For windows: [VB Virtual Cable](http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Cable/) works very well in my experience, For MAC: [Soundflower](https://code.google.com/p/soundflower/downloads/list).  These tools can also be used to redirect audio for recording the output for later analysis with sox or some other tool.
- [This](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/digital-audio-fundamentals) is also a very useful course to understand some of the basics of digital audio before you dive in.
- As mentioned in the comment by @jaket : [PESQ ITU-T P.862](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PESQ)  is the standard for speech quality on telephony systems
- [Acoustic fingerprinting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_fingerprint) is the method used by apps like shazam and could be useful if you want to compare files with an expected result.

I think for anyone trying to automate an audio test you need to first figure out what you want to measure, audio is a very large topic.  I'm still in the process of my own audio automation tests so if anyone else has useful tips on this topic please share.

Answer (score 0):

You might use some AEC lib for this. They are very good in this task as the main purpose of AEC is to find out if two sources are the same or not.

There are a few open source aec implementation, for example a decent one is found as part of the speex codec. You can easily use just the AEC functionality of this library.